# the request in postman works but in angular it doesn't

Tags: django, angular, jwt, http-headers, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1zbZ.png)

I send the bearer token returned by the login and it works

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYkny.png)
the token arrives but the api response is

Authentication credentials were not provided.

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow Please [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Code%20or%20sample%20data%20in,valuable%20data%20that%20is%20limited.)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, solved it by passing a plain object, to the headers property like so!

```
return this.http.post('/test/hello',
        formData,
        {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            },
        }
    );
```